# Search(with grep) in file with variable that contains dot

Tags: bash, awk

A have file **myFile.txt** with 3 column:

```
amy. A B
amy5 B A
amy.smit F P
smit_rees C D
```

A have to write bash script that get value from second column where first column contains value of variable **var**.

Problem is there that when and I execute

```
var='amy.'
grep "$var" myFile.txt | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

result is:

```
A
B
F
```

But real result have to contains only **A**.First column is like username and can contains dots. 
How can I escape special symbols in my variable or somehow to tell on *grep* do not treat them special.

I read about -F flag but then grep match **amy.smit** and **amy.smit** lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the grep man page:

> -w, --word-regexp
>
> Select  only those lines containing matches that form whole words.

```
$ grep -Fw "$var" myFile.txt | awk '{ print $2 }'
A
```

Also, even if we turn off globbing `set -f` before running the grep, we still need to explicitly specify the `-F` switch for grep to not to treat the string as regex.

Comment: `-w` will cause the search string to be literal "amy." WORD making "amy.smit" a different word, and returns `A` record only. It's working on my terminal -- grep 3.1, bash 4.4

Comment: I think you're missing the dot in "amy." which is the search string in entirety.

Comment: Sorry Deepak, I overlooked dot in variable value. Upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want to do a straight string comparison, not a regular expression match at all.

With `awk`:

```
awk -v string="$var" '$1 == string { print $2 }' myFile.txt
```

For the given data and and with `var='amy.'`, this would return only `A`.

Comment: @anubhava No worries.

Answer (score 1):

If your use-case concerns only the `.` character, I would simply transform the pattern to remove the special meaning of `.`:

```
var='amy.'; var=`echo $var | sed 's/\./\\\./g'`; grep "$var " inputfile
```

This causes $var to be `amy\.`

`grep`ing for the space after $var, with `"$var "`, per @ninosanta's answer is also a good idea.

If there might be other regexp meta-characters involved, a more general solution is warranted, but if you need to deal only with `.`, this manipulation is a pragmatic, working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
grep -F "^$var " myFile.txt | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

You know that after the first field there is at least a blank space.
So, i think that it is legitimate pass `"^$var "` (with the blank space) to the grep.

It worked for me.